# How to calculate the intersection points of the same implicit curve in parametric form?

Tags: systems-of-equations, algebraic-curves

Take the following parametric equation of an implicit curve as an example:

$$
\left\{\quad
\begin{array}{rl}
x=& \dfrac{27}{14}  \sin 2 t+\dfrac{15}{14} \sin 3 t \\
y=& \dfrac{27}{14} \cos 2 t-\dfrac{15}{14} \cos 3 t \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

which has five distinct intersection points with itself:

[image]

How to determine the five intersection points in $t$? What kind of equation systems should be used in order to avoid an infinite dimensional solution set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to find the intersections points consists to consider two values of the parameter $t$, namely $t_1$ and $t_2$. Since the point is common, the corresponding coordinates are respectively equal $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. This leads to a system of equations which solving leads a set of values of $t$. Then, keeping only the real roots consistent with the initial equations, one obtains the five points of intersection. The coordinates of the points are given in the table below.

[image]

The exact results are :

First point :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        x=0           \\
        y=-\frac{6}{25}(\sqrt{181}-9) 
      \end{bmatrix}$$
Second and fifth points :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        x=\pm\frac{3}{50}\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}} (\sqrt{181}-9)           \\
        y=\frac{3}{50}(\sqrt{5}+1) (\sqrt{181}-9) 
      \end{bmatrix}$$
Third and fourth points :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
        x=\pm\frac{3}{50}\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}} (\sqrt{181}-9)           \\
        y=-\frac{3}{50}(\sqrt{5}-1) (\sqrt{181}-9) 
      \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! Can this parametric equation be converted into implicit equation?